# Isomorphisms of Graph Embeddings

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

I am having trouble understanding isomorphisms of graph embeddings. How does one distinguish between two graph embeddings on the same surface, and how does one, for example, distinguish between two embeddings $G\to S$ and $G'\to S'$? When do we consider these embeddings "the same"?

Comment: I presume you want to embed the graphs $G$ and $G'$ on the same surface, yes? So $S = S'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. It depends on what *you're* doing, and which embeddings *you* want to consider the same.

The most natural thing I can think of would be to say two graph embeddings $f \colon G \to S$ and $g\colon G' \to S$ are "the same" if there exists a graph isomorphism $\phi\colon G \to G'$ and an automorphism $\alpha$ of your surface $S$ such that $g\phi = \alpha f$. But you could very well weaken the conditions on $\phi$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: But what do you mean by an automorphism of the surface, @Mike? Maybe the appropriate concept is a homeomorphism of the surface that restricts to a isomorphism of the graphs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was thinking "automorphism"="diffeomorphism", but a homeomorphism would be fine too. Like, it depends on what exactly the OP is doing

Comment: @MikePierce Suppose we were talking about graph embeddings on the plane. Is there a maximum number of planar embeddings for a planar graph (for example, could such embeddings be distinguished by the degrees of their faces)? Or are two planar embeddings of the same planar graph considered "different" if you were to, for instance, draw the edges as straight lines in one embedding and not do so in the the other?

Comment: @jg2992 I think this planar case is much more interesting to think about. Between drawing an edge as a straight line and as a squiggly line, I would consider those the same embedding in the plane; there is certainly a homeomorphism of the plane that will "fix" the squiggly line and make it a straight line.

Comment: @jg2992 But as for whether or not there are quantifiable different planar embeddings of a fixed planar graph, I'm not sure. But for how to say two planar embeddings are *different*, I'd say something they're different if there is no homotopy of the plane $P \times [0,1] \to P$ such that the image of the graph embedding is planar for each $i \in [0,1]$. I'd ask this planar graph question separately on this site. If you don't want to, I might. :)

Comment: Sure, I will ask!